# Spring with JUnit Testing and Dependency Injection does not work

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, dependency-injection

I try to use Springs own Dependency Injection in a Junit test case:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.binarisinformatik.api.AppConfig;
import org.binarisinformatik.satzrechner.SatzRechner;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AppConfig.class)
//@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class}) 
public class SatzRechnerTest {

    @Autowired
    private SatzRechner satzRechner;  //SUT

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    //  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SatzRechnerTest.class);
        //satzRechner=context.getBean(SatzRechner.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void addiere_satz_4komma6_zu_zahlwert_10() {

        assertThat("Addition von \"4,6\" ergibt nicht 10!",
                satzRechner.summe("4,6"), is(equalTo(10)));
    }
```

Im testing a class names `SatzRechner` in which Spring should also autowire some variables. Here is my Class under test:

```
@Component
public class SatzRechner {

    @Autowired //@Inject
    private Rechner taschenRechner; 
    @Autowired
    private Zahlenfabrik zahlenfabrik;

    public Integer summe(String zeichenSatz) {
        return taschenRechner.summe(zahlenfabrik.erzeugeZahlen(zeichenSatz));
    }
}
```

And `AppConfig.class` which is using as Configurationfile looks like that:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value={"org.binarisinformatik"})
public class AppConfig {
}
```

What is here the problem?

Comment: he do not autowire the variables - imm getting nullpointerexception....

Comment: `SatzRechner` seems to be in `org.binarisinformatik.satzrechner` package. add it to `componentScan`

Comment: Component scan takes a base package it scans all packages underneath the base package. Adding it won't change a thing. But what isn't working, post the stack trace... A `NullPointer` when auto wiring shouldn't happen as the context blows up before that.

Comment: Can you create a minimal but complete standalone project which illustrates the problem and post it somewhere (github)?

Comment: What about `Rechner` and `Zahlenfabrik`? Are they annotated with `@Component` or another annotation and are they in the same package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use a Spring configuration class, this one must have beans definitions. Please find an example below :

**Test class:**

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.binarisinformatik.api.AppConfig;
import org.binarisinformatik.satzrechner.SatzRechner;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AppConfig.class)
public class SatzRechnerTest {

    @Autowired
    private SatzRechner satzRechner;

    @Test
    public void addiere_satz_4komma6_zu_zahlwert_10() {

        assertThat("Addition von \"4,6\" ergibt nicht 10!",
                satzRechner.summe("4,6"), is(equalTo(10)));
    }
}
```

**Configuration class :**

You have to declare @Bean annotated methods. These beans are managed by Spring container.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    // Beans present here will be injected into the SatzRechnerTest class.

    @Bean
    public SatzRechner satzRechner() {
        return new SatzRechner();
    }

    @Bean
    public Rechner taschenRechner() {
        return new TaschenRechner();
    }

    @Bean
    public Zahlenfabrik zahlenfabrik() {
        return new Zahlenfabrik();
    }
}
```

Note : I let you properly handle returned types here and beans parameters (if present in your context).

Answer (score -1):

There are two things you have to ensure before you run the test case successfully:

1) Classes SatzRechner, Rechner & Zahlenfabrik should be under "org.binarisinformatik" package
2) Classes Rechner & Zahlenfabrik should also be annotated with @Component as SatzRechner.