# Why is my bean not autowired during test?

Tags: java, spring

I've added my bean in `@SpringBootApplication`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestaurantApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RestaurantApplication.class, args);
}
    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    }
}
```

And here is my class to be tested

```
@Service
public class VoteService {
    VoteRepository voteRepository;
    RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;
    Clock clock;
// some methods
}
```

And here is my test

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class DishServiceTest {
    @Mock
    DishRepository dishRepository;
    @Mock
    RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiredMembersInspection")
    @Autowired
    Clock clock;

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiredMembersInspection")
    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    DishService dishService;
// tests where LocalTime.now(clock) is called.
```

The exception I have. What am I doing wrong?

> java.lang.NullPointerException: clock

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring with JUnit Testing and Dependency Injection does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433869/spring-with-junit-testing-and-dependency-injection-does-not-work)

Comment: Are you using @SpringBootTest or @RunWith(SpringRunner) ?

Comment: The fact you added that `@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiredMembersInspection")` should be a hint as to the problem.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel
Thank you for the answer, could you plesae tell, why is my DishService  autowires and I can call methods on it to test it. And Clock not?

Comment: It was not an answer, but a comment. However, the reason is that `DishService` is annotated with `@InjectMocks`, which means Mockito will create an instance using the mocks defined in the test. The `@AutoWired` annotation does nothing here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That is pretty interesting.
I would appreciate it so much if you could tell me, how to inject this bean.
I tried making a TestConfiguration and copied the code of a bean, then - imported it to the test class, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try define  bean  in  config  class

```
@Configuration
public class ExampleConfig {

    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test doesn't try to load any Spring configuration. It is run as a standard unit test (no Spring dependency injection going on, nothing else than your class is known to the test). That is why you get a `NullPointerException` when you run the test. The `@Autowired` is simply not doing anything, and your field is null.

To autowire other beans, you need to make your test aware of Spring.

Here are some different ways of doing that depending on what you want to achieve:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you plesae tell, why is my DishService autowires and I can call methods on it to test it. And Clock not?